# why read() is slower than getc()

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

Why syscall read() is slower than getc() function?

```
for (;;) {
        chr++;
        amr=read(file1, &wc1, 1);
        amr2=read(file2, &wc2, 1);
        if (wc1 == wc2) {
            if (wc1 == '\n')
                line++;
            if (amr == 0) {
                if (eflg)
                    return (1);
                return (0);
            }
            continue;
        }
```

is slower than

```
for (;;) {
    chr++;
    c1 = getc(file1);
    c2 = getc(file2);
    if (c1 == c2) {
        if (c1 == '\n')
            line++;
        if (c1 == EOF) {
            if (eflg)
                return (1);
            return (0);
        }
        continue;
    }
```

when getc() call it uses read() system call, so why is slower?

Comment: How did you determine that it's slower?

Comment: [double](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73264/why-read-is-slower-than-getc)

Comment: Because not buffering

Comment: in file that have 7 878 999 chars(bytes) getc() code works in 3x faster

Comment: getc is buffered (and a macro), read is typically neither, but YMMV

Comment: @BLUEPIXY but getc() read only one character. What is it buffer?

Comment: @NatKup What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @john What is it buffer?

Comment: @NatKup A buffer is a temporary place to store the characters. Say your buffer is 1000 characters big, then the first call to getc reads 1000 characters and fills the buffer with them. The next 999 calls to getc don't do any reading, they just get one character from the buffer so they are very fast. The 1001th call to getc will then fill the buffer again, and so it repeats.

Comment: block reading is more efficient together some degree of reading only one character from a magnetic disk because it is inefficient(Seek, wait, read by call read()). This is called buffering that you set up a kind of buffer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Since disks can only be read 512 bytes at a time there must be buffering in kernel in any case. And in most operating systems that buffering is page granularity, usually 4096 bytes. But buffering in userland still saves a lot of costly context switches.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`read()` involves context switch to kernel, which is relatively slow. When you use it directly and read one byte at a time, you have many context switches. But when you use `getc()`, it will call `read()` once for 4 or 8 kB and than return the characters from that without further context switches until it exhausts the buffer.

If you use `read()` with larger buffer, it would be faster than `getc()`, because the generic buffering of standard C library has some overhead.

(Edit) Note, that disks can only be read in blocks that are 512 bytes for all generally used storage media. So there has to be some buffering in the kernel anyway. And because memory is allocated in pages of 4096 bytes, most systems (Linux certainly does) read at least that much with each request to the physical storage. But the context switch is also expensive, so the additional layer of buffering in userland still saves a lot of time. This buffering is used in all libc IO, which includes everything using `FILE*` (the buffer is part of the `FILE` structure), so `fread()` will be faster than `read()` for small reads.

Answer (score 2):

Answer #1: It isn't slower.

Answer #2: It depends.

You don't want to make a syscall (which includes a context switch on memory-protected systems) for every byte you read from the file. You would, on the first byte-sized access, read an appropriate amount of data (say 4k) into memory, and serve the first byte to the caller. On subsequent byte-sized reads, you don't have to call the kernel or actually access the file at all; you simply pass the next byte from the buffer until you have to read another 4k block.

This is what the standard C library's calls (`fread()`, `fgetc()`, `fgets()` etc. etc.) do by default. You can check `BUFSIZ` to get the default buffer size. You can change the buffer size, or disable buffering altogether, via the `setvbuf()` call.

`read()` is not part of the standard C library, it is a POSIX syscall. Basically, it is the *backend* for the standard C library calls on POSIX systems. (On a Windows system, `fgetc()` would call the Win32 API instead.) As such, `read()` doesn't buffer, and calling it for byte-sized chunks is inefficient as hell. If you call `read()`, you usually do so because you want to do the buffering yourself.

Generally speaking, don't mix POSIX and standard library I/O calls. Use the POSIX API for low-level access, use the standard library for portable convenience (and good default performance).